# php require_once modify the local variable?

Tags: php

In my web page, I wrote:

```
<?php
//define('__PUBLIC__', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/public'); 
$doc_public = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/public';
echo "Before include...<==============>$doc_public";
?>
<?php require_once($doc_public.'/inc/head.php');  ?>
<?php echo "After include...<==============>$doc_public"; ?>
```

And the page shows:
[image]

This firstly happened when I notice the fatal error in the footer, but the head is fine.

Although I can implement define or constant variable to avoid this, I am still curious how it happens.

P.S.: I run this under Apache with a port 8001. This is set in 【apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf】. I am running more than one webapp under this site. I just share this information, as I am not sure this has anything to do with this case.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it's not being modified in `head.php`?

Comment: FYI, `__DIR__` is much more reliable than `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` for creating paths to your scripts

Comment: For all intents and purposes, using an include file is the equivalent of copy pasting the code from the file into the script, at the position it is placed.

Comment: So what's the problem here?  Is it that your `$doc_public` variable appears to change - loosing the slash before public?  If so, look for any references/code that modifies `$doc_public`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you require a file, if a variable is modified it affects the original script as well, that's how it's designed. Require doesn't create a secondary environment separated from the including file, it just adds the PHP code in sequence, exactly like if you had written the code in the initial file.

Have a look at the official PHP documentation, the first example is exactly the same as your case

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

(include is the same as require, the latter just throws an error. For more info about differences between include and require http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)

Comment: _"Require doesn't create a secondary environment separated from the including file"_  true, but `namespace` does 